# I did not understand the use of "(oldest.years || 0)" in this code snippet

Tags: javascript

I didn't understand why the need to use " ||0 " with oldest.years. Wouldn't simply using oldest.years suffice ? This snippet is used to obtain the pilot with highest years of experience.

```
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Poe Dameron",
    years: 14,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
    years: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 41,
    name: "Tallissan Lintra",
    years: 16,
  },
  {
    id: 99,
    name: "Ello Asty",
    years: 22,
  }
];    

var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function (oldest, pilot) {
      return (oldest.years || 0) > pilot.years ? oldest : pilot;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Not if there's no `years` property. In this *specific* code, it doesn't matter. (Although I think a null or undefined > 0 would always be false, but JS coercion...)

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now.

Comment: it is a guard against the case if `oldest.years` is `undefined`. or in proper words, a casting mechanism to keep the left hand side numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if oldest.years is falsy (undefined for example), it will be 0 - a number

comparison operators in js work not only with numbers